# How to convert concurrentbag to list?

Tags: c#, .net

I have few task which I can do in parallel. As list is not thread safe i am using `concurrentbag`. Once all the task are completed I want to convert the `concurrentbag` to list.

I have [searched in MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx) but couldn't find any API which can convert concurrentbag to list in c#. How can I do it?

**Note:** i have to convert to list, It is necessary.

I have other option to apply lock on list but i wanted to use in build `concurrentbag` which is thread safe.

Comment: How hard is to read [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx) ? It implements `IEnumerable<>`, use linq `ToList()` to get list.

Comment: @Sinatr Time for an example on [SO Documentation Beta](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation) ;-)

Comment: did you add using system.linq to your class? you have to be able to use .tolist()

Comment: @Suri - have you succeeded ib solving it with the answers?

Comment: `ToList` returns a collection of Lists for me.. not a List of as expected.. So yea its a bit weird

Answer (score 20):

You could use `ToList` extension method.

```
var list = concurrentBag.ToList();
```

Answer (score 7):

`ConcurrentBag` has the extension method of `.ToList()` - it implements`IEnumerable<T>`

```
var someList = someConcurrentBag.ToList();
```

Answer (score 4):

ConcurrentBag has the ToList() method.

Answer (score 2):

If your internal item are non list then use

```
var someList = someConcurrentBag.ToList();
```

Or you can try as below If each item in the cbag is already a list.

E.g. In my case `ConcurrentBag<List<int>>`

```
ConcurrentBag<List<string>> jobErrorsColl = new ConcurrentBag<List<string>>();

// Got something in jobErrorsColl
List<string> multipleJobErrors = new List<string>();
List<string> singleJobErrors = new List<string>();

while (jobErrorsColl.IsEmpty)
{
    jobErrorsColl.TryPeek(out singleJobErrors);
    multipleJobErrors.AddRange(singleJobErrors);
}

return multipleJobErrors;
```

MSDN link is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx) for the same

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to convert concurrentbag to list:

```
var list = = someConcurrentBag.SelectMany(r => r).ToList();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: marked up comment above... seems silly if it the "most" useful post